# perl mcpan fails with certificate errors

Tags: perl, cpan

I'm using perl 5.36.0 installed with perlbrew (yes, I need to use that version) but can't install any modules due to certificate errors like below

```
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
Reading '/home/mps/.cpan/Metadata'
Warning: Found only 0 objects in /home/mps/.cpan/Metadata

Trying with
    /usr/bin/wget -O "/home/mps/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp13585"
to get
    https://cpan.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
--2023-08-23 15:42:42--  https://cpan.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Resolving cpan.org (cpan.org)... 151.101.193.55, 151.101.129.55, 151.101.65.55, ...
Connecting to cpan.org (cpan.org)|151.101.193.55|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify cpan.org's certificate, issued by ‘CN=R3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US’:
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Some information. I can't `wget` from cpan on Ubuntu 16.04

```wget  https://cpan.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
--2023-08-23 22:08:57--  https://cpan.org/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Resolving cpan.org (cpan.org)... 151.101.65.55, 151.101.1.55, 151.101.129.55, ...
Connecting to cpan.org (cpan.org)|151.101.65.55|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify cpan.org's certificate, issued by ‘CN=R3,O=Let's Encrypt,C=US’:
  Issued certificate has expired.
To connect to cpan.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.```
but the same command works on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Right, so your old, out-of-support OS doesn't have the right certificates in its trust store. That's not really Perl's or CPAN's problem, it's a "your computer can't talk to half the internet in 2023" problem.